# Unable to import local photo in react native. Getting Error "None of these files exist:"

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, import

I am trying to import a png photo from a local folder in my react native project using `import image from '../img/fittings.PNG';`.

But I get an error saying the file doesn't exist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEomy.png

For reference my files look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LegiM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's the right way. You could try:

```
import { Image } from "react-native";

<Image source={require("../img/fittings.PNG")} />
```

or whatever the path to your image is.

Answer (score 3):

In React Native *import* is using for importing modules who has export method inside , if you want to import any image you need to require it in the page you want to use by using ***require()***  method:

```
import { Image } from "react-native";

<Image source={require("../pathToImage.ext")} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a server such as npm, yarn or expo and you've included your image while server is running, you just need to restart the server.

Theoretically the folder was not there when you ran the server previously.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. As long as the folder is a sub-folder of the the one the site is being served from, there should be no issue.